# How can i achieve this style in Html/Css?

Tags: html, css, web

i want to add these lines you can see at the bottom of the Journal and transaction how can i achieve this i done everything i am new to CSS

[image: Form]

Comment: What do you mean by these lines? Please use any code playground to show us your code, so we can make our minds up (https://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/)

Comment: This would probably just be `text-decoration:underline`, or a `border-bottom: 1px solid gray`

Comment: @CarlosAraya please check the picture labled Form

Comment: I did checked the image. Still, I don't understand what "_... how can i achieve this i done everything_" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add border on each element like this:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">Journal Type:</div>
```

Or create class in `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <style>
      .border{
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      }
    </style>
</head>
```

and add it to your element:

```
<div class="border">Journal Type:</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `<hr>` tag and see if that works for what you need.